# Problem with Toshiba satellite c55t-c5300

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, toshiba

I started working few months ago with Linux and decided to go all-in and switch from windows to linux.
I installed ubuntu 16.04 and the wifi isn't working at all, tried lots of guides online with no luck about my specifications (no worries- after failing the first time I reinstalled it).

it will probably help to solve it quicker:

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network
```

gave me:

```
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

Since I don't know much yet about this system a full guide will be more than appreciated.

Thank you,
Danor